# SQL Server 2012 Container Image Support

Tags: sql-server, docker

Our business runs on Windows Server 2012r2, and we're interested in exploring use of SQL Server in Docker containers for Dev and QA support.  I've looked at Microsoft's new images for Windows Server 2016, but see the two Express images (2014 and 2016) have been deprecated in favor of the vNext image.    Has anyone heard what MSFT's plans are for SQL Server support, or if they provide support for Windows Server 2012?